# PL/SQL: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with condition variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a function in PL/SQL written like this

```
IF p_class IS NOT NULL
THEN
v_conditions := ' WHERE class = :p_class '
ELSE
v_conditions := ' WHERE 1 = :p_class '
p_class := 1
END IF;
```

I want to execute query with given `p_class`:

```
v_query := v_query || v_conditions;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query USING p_class
```

Now I want to check if my `p_class` is not exists, I won't have `v_conditions` in my query.
Is there any better way instead of using `WHERE 1 = :p_class`?

I try to refactor my function to check if `p_class` is null, I won't have to add `v_conditions` to query, but I get an error:

> `bind variable does not exists`.

I also try `v_conditions := ' WHERE class = ' || p_class` but I'm afraid that it will get SQL injection so I didn't use it.

Comment: What do you mean by "I won't have v_conditions in my query"? If you can execute it, then of course you also can read (and analyze) the string.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I mean if p_class is exists, I will concat the v_conditions into my query but if it is null, I won't concat the v_conditions

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach treats the effect, not the cause.

If you know in advance (or at least before execution) that you won't need a condition, I'd just skip everything else directly:

```
 IF p_class IS NULL THEN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query;
 ELSE
     v_query := v_query || v_conditions;
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query USING p_class;
 END IF;
```

In general I prefer to filter-out such specialized cases directly from the condition that would "trigger" or need them.

If you really want an inline method of doing this, you can't, because of `USING` and a `1=1` is probably the only way (especially considering multiple parameters on a case-by-case basis).

Comment: What about having more than 1 parameter? In my function, I have about 5 paramter and if I have to check like this, it will take a lot of effort to do this

Comment: To be fair, I dislike your concatenation way as well unless it's for a school project. If it's for a production environment, it's just begging wrong-doers to do some SQL injection on your systems. But that's just a personal note :) There's also some overhead because of dynamic code there as well. Please keep both of these points in mind as well.

Comment: Well I was afraid we'd get into a different-param problem :) In general The way I did it was to build prototype functions (meaning those with the same signature) and just fill parameters that were needed. This would take some work to refactor but it's a more linear approach. I usually did it in a separate helper package and then just added function calls. The difference is, you seem to generate dynamic procedure or function bodies, which doesn't really help with maintenance or readability.

Comment: In my case, I wrote my function or procedure in its package (or standalone, depending on the case), added each dynamic function / procedure in a table, and executed that based on the resulted id from the query that determined what function or procedure to execute. As for the parameters that I didn't need, I'd just use NULL. Of course, if your code is extremely versatile and you can't use a prototype, then using dynamic code is a bad design choice since it won't be possible.

Comment: I also don't like concatenation like this but I have no other way, if it have only 1 parameter then it would be more easy, but it have 5 and may be can be more so I don't think it will be easy to handle them

Comment: As I said, if your 5 parameters are always the same type (or with little variations and refactoring could allow you to change the order or alternatively use `=>`), then try using my approach: dynamic function / procedure name vs dynamic body. If you want performance, there is a compromise where you need to draw a line at.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in a single statement, no IF needed:

```
DECLARE
  l_ename VARCHAR2(100);
  l_statement VARCHAR2(500) := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp WHERE ename = :ename or :ename IS NULL';
  l_result NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_ename := 'KING';
  --l_ename := NULL
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_statement INTO l_result USING l_ename, l_ename;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
END;
/
```

--update--
if there are multiple parameters and the check of the NULL value has performance consequences then you can try the following. execute a `1=1` first if the parameter value is null. This will be evaluated and yield true so the next condition will be ignored.

```
DECLARE
  l_ename VARCHAR2(100);
  l_job VARCHAR2(100);
  l_statement VARCHAR2(500) := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp WHERE 1 = 1 ';
  l_condition VARCHAR2(100);
  l_result NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_ename := NULL;
  l_job := 'CLERK';
  IF l_ename IS NULL THEN
    l_statement := l_statement ||' AND (1 = 1 OR 1 = :p1) ';
  ELSE
    l_statement := l_statement ||' AND ename = :p1 ';
  END IF;
  IF l_job IS NULL THEN
    l_statement := l_statement ||' AND (1 = 1 OR 1 = :p2) ';
  ELSE
    l_statement := l_statement ||' AND job = :p2 ';
  END IF;
    
  dbms_output.put_line(l_statement);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_statement INTO l_result USING l_ename, l_job;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
END;
/
```

Comment: I try `OR p_class IS NULL` before but it take a lot of time to check the parameter is Null or not because I have aboutt 5 parameter and it cause timeout when calling my API

Comment: That wasn't in your original question, I just answered what you asked. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an `IF` statement or dynamic SQL, just use a static query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  (:p_class IS NULL OR class = :p_class)
AND    (:p_other IS NULL OR other = :p_other)
AND    (:p_extra IS NULL OR extra = :p_extra)
```

Comment: Actually I have tried before but it take almost 2 minutes to execute and cause timeout when calling API so I don't use it anymore

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 2-3 parameters, then you will end up either in a big bunch of `IF-THEN_ELSE` statements or an ugly and not optimized query. In such case I suggest the [DBMS_SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-C96D5BAA-29A9-4AB5-A69E-E31228ECC9E9) package. Would be like this:

```
DECLARE

    v_query VARCHAR2(30000);
    v_conditions VARCHAR2(30000);
    cur INTEGER;
    res INTEGER;
    v_count INTEGER;

BEGIN

    IF p_class IS NOT NULL THEN
        v_conditions := v_conditions || 'AND class = :p_class ';
    END IF;
    IF p_other IS NOT NULL THEN
        v_conditions := v_conditions || 'AND other = :p_other ';
    END IF;
    IF p_extra IS NOT NULL THEN
        v_conditions := v_conditions || 'AND extra = :p_extra ';
    END IF;
    v_conditions := REGEXP_REPLACE(v_conditions, '^AND ', 'WHERE ');
    v_query := 'SELECT COUNT(*) as C FROM your_table '||v_conditions;
    
    cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, v_query, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    
    IF p_class IS NOT NULL THEN
        DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE (cur, ':p_class', p_class);
    END IF;
    IF p_other IS NOT NULL THEN
        DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE (cur, ':p_other', p_other);
    END IF;
    IF p_extra IS NOT NULL THEN
        DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE (cur, ':p_extra', p_extra);
    END IF;
    
    res := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE_AND_FETCH(cur, TRUE);
    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(cur, 'C', v_count);
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur); 

END;
```

Comment: I was tempted to recommend this as it's the closest thing managing dynamic code, but I wasn't sure of the performance overhead of DBMS_SQL.* as compared to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. I'd venture to guess EXEC IMED is faster, but I admit DBMS_SQL grants more control at the expense of verbosity (although if written in an utility function or procedure it wouldn't be that nasty.

Comment: I think you need to add a space after each bind variable in `v_conditions` concat-ing though. Else you might get `AND class = :p_classAND other = :p_other` after concatenation if more than one param is sent.

Comment: Performance wise it should make no difference. `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is just a shortcut. 20 years ago it was a difference, however it would only matter if you execute thousands of commands in a loop. The performance bottleneck will be always the SELECT statement itself.

Comment: Yes, the space was missing. I correct it. You can put the parameters also in an array (PL/SQL collection) and loop over it. Then the code will become even shorter.

Answer (score 0):

```
with
   binds as (
      select :p1 p1,
             :p2 p2
      from   dual
   )
select [...]
from   binds
join   emp
on     binds.p1 = emp.emp_id
```

Always include all binds in the `binds`-CTE, so you can live with a single `execute immediate`.